# Showing results in good table form and columnize it

Tags: python, multiple-columns

This is a script that I wrote for getting alexa rank.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import requests
from lxml import html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'usage: python %s <file-urls>' % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(2)

filename = sys.argv[1]
urls = open(filename)
for site in urls:
    try:
        url="http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/"+site
        content=requests.get(url).content
        tree=html.fromstring(content)
        RANK=tree.xpath('//strong[@class="metrics-data align-vmiddle"]/text()')
        print "Site:",site+"Global Rank:",RANK[0]+"\t"+"Country Rank:",RANK[1]
#        print 'Site:%s Global Rank:%2s Country Rank:%2s' % (site, RANK[0], RANK[1])
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print "Keyboar Interruption!"
        sys.exit(0)
```

RESULTS:

```
Site: google.com
Global Rank: 1  Country Rank: 1
Site: yahoo.com
Global Rank: 4  Country Rank: 4
Site: bing.com
Global Rank: 23 Country Rank: 14
```

The results are not satisfactory. Could you show how the better way to columnize the results?

Comment: I want to know why site is in upper line and how to correct it

Comment: Because there is `\n` in the end of your `site` variable. try to strip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site` contains newline as it is presumably read from a file with one word per line. Strip it before you use it and the newline, along with any whitespace, is gone.

Also consider using string notation rather than string appending.

```
for site in urls:
    site = site.strip()
    url="http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/%s" % (site,)
    <..>
```